# Beamer: Sub-itemize environment leaves gap behind

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize, animations

I have a nested `itemize` environment, which should only be shown on the first slide:

```tex
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> A
        \begin{itemize}[<1>]
            \item A1
            \item A2
            \item A3
        \end{itemize}
        \item<2-> B
        \begin{itemize}[<2>]
            \item B1
            \item B2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The first slide looks good:

[image: first slide]

However, there's a gap on the second slide:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is actually wanted, because you use overlays. The space that is needed for stuff that is hidden due to being an overlay is kept. Use `<only@1>` instead of `<1>` for the nested `itemize` if you don't want the space to be kept.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht), the following solution should work:

```tex
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> A
        \begin{itemize}[<only@1>]
            \item A1
            \item A2
            \item A3
        \end{itemize}
        \item<2-> B
        \begin{itemize}[<only@2>]
            \item B1
            \item B2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Second slide:

[image: new second slide]

For similar issues, the `\only` command may turn out useful.